# Why we can use the trig substitution $\int f(\tan(x))dx = \int\frac{f(y)}{1+y^2}dy$

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometric-integrals

Why we can use the substitution: $$\int f(\tan(x))dx = \int\frac{f(y)}{1+y^2}dy$$

I know that:

$$\int \frac{1}{x^2+1}dx = \arctan(x) +c $$

I want to know why we can use that substitution

Comment: if $y=\tan x$ then $x=\arctan y$. Find $dx$

Comment: This is a reasonable question that has been asked on this site before, about what $dx$ really is, and how to interpret these manipulations. In the normal $u = f(x)$ substitution, you are doing something fundamentally different then when you write $x = g(y)$. The technical terms are pullbacks and pushforwards. This is all explained in the book by Callahan "Advanced Calculus, a Geometric View." The first chapter explains these at the level a calculus student will appreciate, without the machinery of differential forms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Integration by substitution is a theorem that states

$$ \int F(x) \ \text dx = \int F(G(y)) \cdot G'(y) \ \text dy $$

for indefinite integrals. You're probably used to using this as-is, i.e. you see something like

$$ \int \exp(y^2/2) \cdot y \ \text dy $$

and note that $F = \exp$ and $G(y) = y^2/2$ implies that $G'(y) = y$, and so you can apply the above theorem to evaluate the equivalent integral

$$ \int \exp(x) \ \text dx $$

However, the example you've given looks to be in the form of

$$ \int f(g(x)) \ \text dx = \int f(y) \cdot (g^{-1}(y))' \ \text dy $$

Let $F = f\circ g$ and $G = g^{-1}$, so then $f = f \circ g \circ g^{-1} = F \circ G$. With this renaming, the above equation becomes

$$ \int F(x) \ \text dx = \int F(G(y)) \cdot G'(y) \ \text dy $$

which you can now see is equivalent to the original statement of the theorem. Of course, this makes the assumption that $g$ is at least right-invertible, but this is true for $\tan$ since $\tan\circ\tan^{-1}$ is the identity function.